# Closing HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I have a little bug in the code.
I create and open a new instance of HttpSelfHostServer.
In some special cases i am forced to close the current server object, and open new one.
So i call the close function(And dispose the object) :

```
_server.CloseAsync().Wait();
_server.Dispose();
_server = null;
```

But still when i try to open a new Service with the same endpoint i get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A registration already exists for URI
```

And suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CloseAsync` method on the class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The general advice for TAP is not to block on async calls. That means no calling Wait or Result as it can easily cause deadlocks.

See more [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

It is difficult to say without seeing more of your code what exactly would be deadlocking in this case. But if this is the issue, the fix is simple and easy to test

Instead of doing this :

```
_server.CloseAsync().Wait();
```

Do this :

```
await _server.CloseAsync();
```

Similarly if you are doing this :

```
_server.StartAsync().Wait();
```

Instead do this

```
await _server.StartAsync();
```